# Does logistic regression always find global optimum, assuming that the optimisation converges?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, minimization, maximize, convergence

I am uncertain if this is the case both in general:

- does logistic regression always find global optimum?

and in particular

- does logistic regression always find global optimum when that the optimisation converges?

Answer (score 3):

When the data are separable, the optimum is at infinity, so you will never reach it. Normally, though, any optimization algorithm you are using will reach a point from which no noticeable improvement can be attained by iterating further.

An adequately tuned algorithm will eventually find the global optimum if this is not the case, because the loss function is [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function).

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify why it finds the global optimum because the loss function is convex?

Comment: Convex (concave) functions only have one minimum (maximum). Iterative optimization algorithms such as gradient descent or Newton's method, often employed for logistic regression, search for directions in space in which the objective function decreases (increases). Therefore, they will eventually encounter the optimum, provided that the update step is sufficiently small. I added a link.