# Why does LogisticRegression give the same result every time, even with different random state?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am not an expert on logistic regression, but I thought when solving it using `lgfgs` it was doing optimization, finding local minima for the objective function. But every time I run it using `scikit-learn`, it is returning the same results, even when I feed it a different random state.

Below is code that reproduces my issue.

#### First set up the problem by generating data

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import datasets

# generate data
X, y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=1000, 
                                   n_features=10, 
                                   n_redundant=4,
                                   n_clusters_per_class=1, 
                                   random_state=42)


# Set up the test/training data
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25)
```

#### Second, train the model and inspect results

```
# Set up a different random state each time
rand_state = np.random.randint(1000)
print(rand_state)
model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000,
                           solver='lbfgs',
                           random_state=rand_state)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
conf_mat = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(y_pred[:20],"\n", conf_mat)
```

I get the same `y_pred` (and obviously confusion matrix) every time I run this even though I'm using the `lbfgs` solver with a different random state each run. I'm confused, as I thought this was a stochastic solver that was traveling down a gradient into a local minimum.

Maybe I'm not properly randomizing the initial state? I haven't been able to figure it out from [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

### Discussion of Related Question

There is a related question, which I didn't find during my research:
[Does logistic regression always find global optimum, assuming that the optimisation converges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785395/does-logistic-regression-always-find-global-optimum-assuming-that-the-optimisat)

The answer there is that the cost function is convex, so *if* the numerical solution is well-behaved, it will find a global minimum. That is, there aren't a bunch of local minima that your optimization algorithm will get stuck in: it will reach the same (global) minimum each time (perhaps depending on the solver you choose?).

However, in the comments someone pointed out, depending on what solvers you choose there are cases when you will not reach the same solution, that it depends on the `random_state` parameter. At the very least, I think this would be helpful to resolve.

Comment: A logistic regression problem (except for linearly separable ones) has no local minimum (or rather, exactly one, the global minimum).  https://stackoverflow.com/q/40785395/10495893

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize logistic regression is a convex optimization problem (I know linear regression is). That would explain why all these solutions are so well-behaved!

Comment: A couple of references on the convexity of the cost function in logistic regression: https://www.baeldung.com/cs/cost-function-logistic-regression-logarithmic-expr  and
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582452/logistic-regression-prove-that-the-cost-function-is-convex  . @BenReiniger if you turn your insight into an answer I'll accept it.  It does make me wonder what the point of the `random_state` parameter is. I guess in *theory* convexity should yield nice results each time, but in practice things can get ugly sometimes as the solutions aren't analytically derived.

Comment: It might be interesting to set `class_sep` to near `0` in `make_classification` to make classification much harder/impossible.  I imagine that `LogisticRegression`'s `random_state` will have an effect then since class separation will be difficult and starting point, etc., will have some effect on its results.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen to answer some details around non-converging paths to the global optimum.  (In case the reopen doesn't happen, a comment-size summary: the docs for `LogisticRegression` say `random_state` only applies to three of the solvers, not including the `lbfgs` used in the Question here.  In initial attempts to get different partial solutions, I haven't had luck in making `liblinear` differ either, which may be worth exploring.  `saga` and `sag` readily give different answers with different seeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me put in the answer what got this closed as duplicate earlier: a logistic regression problem (without perfect separation) has a global optimum, and so there are no local optima to get stuck in with different random seeds.  If the solver converges satisfactorily, it will do so on the global optimum.  So the only time `random_state` can have any effect is when the solver fails to converge.

Now, [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) for `LogisticRegression`'s parameter `random_state` states:

> Used when `solver` == ‘sag’, ‘saga’ or ‘liblinear’ to shuffle the data. [...]

So for your code, with `solver='lbfgs'`, indeed there is no expected effect.

It's not too hard to make `sag` and `saga` fail to converge, and with different `random_state`s to end at different solutions; to make it easier, set `max_iter=1`.  `liblinear` apparently does not use the `random_state` unless solving the dual, so also setting `dual=True` admits different solutions.  I found that thanks to [this comment on a github issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4760#issuecomment-105932019) (the rest of the issue may be worth reading for more background).